# python pyaudio errors on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pyaudio

hi so i had this program working fine on my windows machine but then i get errors on my raspberry pi and i'm not sure why because as far as i am aware data isn't referenced before assignment. im not sure what to do to fix this any help would be greatly appreciated.
this is the code

```
import pyaudio
import numpy
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
RATE = 44100
BUFFER = 882

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    format = pyaudio.paFloat32,
    channels = 1,
    rate = RATE,
    input = True,
    output = False,
    frames_per_buffer = BUFFER
)

fig = plt.figure()
line1 = plt.plot([],[])[0]
line2 = plt.plot([],[])[0]

r = range(0,int(RATE/2+1),int(RATE/BUFFER))
l = len(r)

def init_line():
        line1.set_data(r, [-1000]*l)
        line2.set_data(r, [-1000]*l)
        return (line1,line2,)
# def grab():
#         time.sleep(3)
#         print(line1.get_data())
#         # return (line1,line2,)
def update_line(i):
    try:
        data = numpy.fft.rfft(numpy.fromstring(
            stream.read(BUFFER), dtype=numpy.float32)
        )
    except IOError:
        pass
    data = numpy.log10(numpy.sqrt(
        numpy.real(data)**2+numpy.imag(data)**2) / BUFFER) * 10
    line1.set_data(r, data)
    line2.set_data(numpy.maximum(line1.get_data(), line2.get_data()))
    # print(data[0])
    if data[0] > -30:
        print("red")
    elif data[0] <-30 and data[0]>-50:
        print("amber")
    else: print("green")
    # if linee2[0].any() >2000:
    #     print("red")
    # else: print("green")
    return (line1,line2,)

plt.xlim(0, RATE/2+1)
plt.ylim(-60, 0)
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel('dB')
plt.title('Spectrometer')
plt.grid()

line_ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, update_line, init_func=init_line, interval=0, blit=True
)

plt.show()
```

and this is what errors it outputs when it is ran

````
    numpy.real(data)**2+numpy.imag(data)**2) / BUFFER) * 10
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment```
````

Comment: In the case where your `try...except` silently fails, there is no assignment to `data`. That is causing *referenced before assignment*, and is the reason why people say that `except: pass` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: even when removed i still get an error 
[errno -9988] stream closed

Comment: So that makes clear that the real problem is an `IOError` caused by `stream.read(BUFFER)`. That explains why it worked before on Windows but not now on the Raspberry Pi. What your code is trying to read can clearly be opened, otherwise `p.open()` would have failed, but there is a problem with reading it.

Comment: Try posting a fresh question with the real error message, that makes it clear that you have a `pyaudio` problem and not just a basic coding error.